# How to get list of all child process spawned by a script

Tags: bash, unix, shell, process, bash-scripting

**Context:**

Users provide me their custom scripts to run. These scripts can be of any sort like scripts to start multiple GUI programs, backend services. I have no control over how the scripts are written. These scripts can be of blocking type i.e. execution waits till all the child processes (programs that are run sequentially) exit

```
#exaple of blocking script
echo "START"
first_program 
second_program 
echo "DONE"
```

or non blocking type i.e. ones that fork child process in the background and exit something like

```
#example of non-blocking script
echo "START"
first_program &
second_program &
echo "DONE"
```

**What am I trying to achieve?**

User provided scripts can be of any of the above two types or mix of both. My job is to run the script and wait till all the processes started by it exit and then shutdown the node. If its of blocking type, case is plain simple i.e. get the PID of script execution process and wait till ps -ef|grep -ef PID has no more entries. Non-blocking scripts are the ones giving me trouble

Is there a way I can get list of PIDs of all the child process spawned by execution of a script? Any pointers or hints will be highly appreciated

Comment: I don;t think it is possible after the parent script has ended unless you can capture the parent's PID. If you are launching the scripts, you could wrap them in something like `pid$(foo.sh; echo $!)` which will give you the PID of `foo.sh` so you can then use `ps --ppid`. Will that work?

Comment: Do the scripts have to run under the UID of the author user?  If not, can you create a dummy user just for this purpose?  You wouldn’t even need `grep`, just `ps –udummy_user`.  Also, look at process groups.

Comment: This is more a type of workaround than a solution for your initial question: Open a new bash session. You can list all processes spawned from this shell using `ps` without any arguments (should be only `bash` and `ps` in the beginning).  Start your script there. After it finished, wait until `ps | wc -l` reaches your expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for your responses.. I got the solution on stackoverflow

You can use wait to wait for all the background processes started by userscript to complete. Since wait only works on children of the current shell, you'll need to source their script instead of running it as a separate process.

**( source userscript; wait )**

Sourcing the script in an explicit subshell should simulate starting a new process closely enough. If not, you can also background the subshell, which forces a new process to be started, then wait for it to complete.

**( source userscript; wait ) & wait**

Here is the link for original answer by @chepner : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663196/how-to-get-list-of-all-child-process-spawned-by-a-script/18663969?noredirect=1#18663969

Comment: I thought about this as well, but this solution fails when _userscript_ starts a subscript in background which then starts another script in background. Your `wait` command will then wait for the children of _userscript_ but not for its grandchildren.

Comment: @Tim   Just realized that :(

Answer (score 10):

To answer your question directly, the command

```
jobs -p
```

gives you the list of all child processes.

### Alternative #1

But in your case it might be easier to just use the command `wait` without any params:

```
first_program &
second_program &
wait
```

This will wait until **ALL** child processes have finished.

### Alternative #2

Another alternative is using `$!` to get the PID of the last program and perhaps accumulate in a variable, like so:

```
pids=""
first_program &
pids="$pids $!"
second_program &
pids="$pids $!"
```

and then use wait with that (this is in case you only want to wait for a subset of you child processes):

```
wait $pids
```

### Alternative #3

OR, if you want to wait only until **ANY** process has finished, you can use

```
wait -n $pids
```

### Bonus info

If you want a sigterm to your bash script to close your child processes as well, you will need to propagate the signal with something like this (put this somewhere at the top, before starting any process):

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
```